# If $\{x,\{x,y\}\} = \{z, \{z,t\}\}$, then must it be $x = z$ and $y = t$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

> If $\{x,\{x,y\}\} = \{z, \{z,t\}\}$, then must it be $x = z$ and $y = t$?

Can you explain, or can you give hint?

Answer (score 2):

I'll give part of a proof that shows the idea.

Let $\{x,\{x,y\}\}=\{z,\{z,t\}\}$.

Then $x\in\{z,\{z,t\}\}$, so either $x=z$ or $x=\{z,t\}$, by the definition of pair.

Also $z\in\{x,\{x,y\}\}$, so either $z=x$ or $z=\{x,y\}$.

Now suppose that $x=\{z,t\}$. If $z=x$, then $x=\{x,t\}$, but then $x\in x$, which is proibited by the axiom of relugarity. If $z=\{x,y\}$, then $x \in z \in x$, which is also proibited by the axiom of relugarity. We conclude that $x \not = \{z,t\}$, so it must be that $x=z$.

$y=t$ can be shown similarily.